# Error ReferenceError: CanvasGradient is not defined

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I am trying to create a line chart using chartjs-node package. Below is the code. When I give the data of dataset as a small set like data: [20, 15, 60, 60, 65, 30, 70], it works fine. But if I change it to a list that I want to populate as in dataFirst dataset below, I get the error  "ReferenceError: CanvasGradient is not defined". I donot understand the reason. Please help. Thanks.

```
public createChart(cData) {
    const chartNode = new chart(1000, 800);

    const dataFirst = {
        label: 'Heat Sink',
        data: cData,
        lineTension: 0.3,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'red',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 15,
        pointHitRadius: 30,
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        pointStyle: 'rect',
    };

    const dataSecond = {
        label: 'TVK Channel 9',
        data: [20, 15, 60, 60, 65, 30, 70],
        lineTension: 0.3,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'purple',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'purple',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHitRadius: 30,
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
    };

    const chartOptions = {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
            boxWidth: 80,
            fontColor: 'black',
            },
        },
    };

    const speedData = {
        labels: ['0s', '10s', '20s', '30s', '40s', '50s', '60s'],
        datasets: [dataFirst, dataSecond],
    };

    const chartJsOptions = {
        type: 'line',
        data: speedData,
        options: chartOptions,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The number of labels should match the number of data points.

Answer (score 1):

In `canvas` for node implementation you need to export CanvasGradient class yourself. According to this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/990
You can do this:

```
["CanvasRenderingContext2D", "CanvasPattern", "CanvasGradient"].forEach(obj => {
  console.log(obj, canvas[obj])
  global[obj] = canvas[obj]
})
```